# "if" function, reading stored data problem. C programming

Tags: c

This is using file

FIRST FILE:

```
Hill Man
LC12CS6789
B
A
D
C
A
```

SECOND FILE:

```
B
C
D
C
A
```

MY CODE IS THIS:

```
FILE *student, *ans;
student = fopen("StudentAnswer.txt", "r");
ans = fopen("CorrectAnswer.txt", "r");

fscanf(student, "%[^\n]", name);   //have to printf name at the end
fscanf(student, "%s", id);    //also have to printf student id

for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
{
    fscanf(student, "%c", &array1[i]);
    fscanf(ans, "%c", &array2[i]);
    printf("%c  %c\n", array1[i], array2[i]);  //no prob here

    if(array1[i] != array2[i])  //but my "if" cannot properly read my stored data
    {
        printf("NOT SAME"); 
    }

}
```

I have to compare "students answer" with "correct answer".
Then display the which question the student got wrong, including her name and id on the top of the displayed.
I have no prob when I only print the arrays data, as it arrange properly, but then "if" cannot evaluate stored data properly, thus i cannot compare both arrays.
It is like i have additional stored data, other than the printf displayed

Notes: I have to read 2 files, then display the result onscreen, so no output files

My thought: Looks like the "student" name and id mess up the students's answer.

UPDATE: My code work, just did like **Osiris** advised.

NEW PROB: I have extra line that I really have no idea with at the end of the display now, that is

`NOT SAME`

p/s: The symbol is really like that

Comment: Maybe its because `fscanf` leaves the newline in the buffer? Try `" %c"` instead of `"%c"` for `fscanf`.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post text as text.

Comment: Your question is really difficult to read. Try to use uppercase letters at the start of a sentence.

Comment: i already add the files

Comment: `fscanf` actually returns a value - worth checking.

Comment: After getting the answer to the originally stated problem (per your comment above) it appears you tacked on another question.  This is typically not recommended.  If the answer to your original question is resolved, it is better to create a new post for new questions.

Comment: okay man,thanks for the advise

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because fscanf leaves the newline in the buffer? Try " %c" instead of "%c" for fscanf. – Osiris